# Valgrind error: Invalid read of size 1

Tags: pointers, valgrind

I cant find the error in this code, Im looking at it for hours... Valgrind says:

```
==23114== Invalid read of size 1
==23114== Invalid write of size 1
```

I tried debugging with some printfs, and i think that the error is in this function.

```cpp
void rdm_hide(char *name, Byte* img, Byte* bits, int msg, int n, int size)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int r;/
    Byte* used;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int p;

    fp = fopen(name, "wb");

    used = malloc(sizeof(Byte) * msg);


    for(i = 0; i < msg; i++)
        used[i] = -1;


    while(i < 3)
    {
        if(img[j] == '\n')
            i++;
        j++;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < msg; i++)
    {
        r = genrand_int32();
        p = r % n;

        if(!search(p, used, msg))
        {
            used[i] = (Byte)p;

            if(bits[i] == (Byte)0)
                img[j + p] = img[j + p] & (~1);
            else if(bits[i] == (Byte)1)
                img[j + p] = img[j + p] | 1;
        }
        else
            i --;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        fputc( (char) img[i], fp);

    fclose(fp);
    free(used);
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: can you run valgrind with option **--read-var-info=yes** and share the output?

Comment: It may be occurring when you're writing to and reading from the array being pointed to by img. Use gdb to pinpoint what line this is occurring in.

Answer (score 0):

> ==23114== Invalid read of size 1
>   ==23114== Invalid write of size 1

I am pretty sure that's not *all* valgrind says.

You should

1. Build your program with debug info (most likely `-g` flag). This will let valgrind tell you *exactly* which line triggers invalid read and write
2. If the problem doesn't become obvious, edit your question and include *entire* valgrind output.
3. Re-running `valgrind --track-origins=yes your-exe` may provide additional useful info.

Lastly, your algorithm *appears* to be totally bogus. As far as I can tell, the `j` becomes 3 after the first `while` loop and never changes after that (in which case you should just use `const int j = 3;` and do away with `j++`). Also, you reference `img[j + p]`, where `p` is between `0` and `n`. If `n` is indeed the size of `img`, then it's little surprise that `j + p` indexes outside of the `img` limits, and triggers both errors.